# Correct structure of json API request

Tags: jquery, json

I am attempting to query the Plivo api. One requirement is that the request is encoded as Content-Type 'application/json'.

I have modified some code, from an example here on stackoverflow, but no result is returned. The code is:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://myID:myToken@api.plivo.com/v1/",
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ region: "California", prefix: 415 }),
            contentType: "application/json",
            complete: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            $("#result").html(data);
             }
    });
```

What's wrong? Is the URL string properly formed? In the data section, should region be surrounded by single quotes?

This is very exasperating and I would welcome some help, please.

Comment: What does the remote server return? Even in unsuccessful requests a good server will tell you what's wrong in the response and in the status code.

Comment: thank, in the alert window it says -  [object][Object] there is no message so, it seems, my script is not talking to the api.

Comment: dont you need dataType:json for jquery?

Comment: still returns [object][Object] is the URL properly formed, do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try making your request like this.
The important part should be dataType and contentType

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ region: "California", prefix: 415 }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        //do whatever you want with the returned data
        //console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I updated my answer...That was just some generic response handling.  do whatever you want on the success function, or use complete like you were previously.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is returning a JSON object and you want to see the contents of the object instead of `[object][Object]`, you can convert the object to a string using:

`alert( JSON.stringify( data ) )`

If you want it to look more readable:

`alert( JSON.stringify( data, null, "\t" ) )`